# Class instances share the value of a data member

Tags: java, datamember

I am writting a program to display a list multiple choice questions.I am having a problem with the value stored in the ChoiceString data member of my java class. Each instance of the class should have its own value of ChoiceString, but for some reason ChoiceString only hold the value initialized by the first instance and share it with other instances, where I want each instance to have its own ChoiceString unique value. how can I fix that?

The following is my code:

```
   public class AllChoiceQuestion extends ChoiceQuestion{

  private String note = "Note: The following question has one or more correct choices\nYou must give the number(s) of ALL correct anwers, in order,\nto get full credit andsperated by spaces";
  private int count =0;
      // A varabile that will hold the user answer 
  private String choiceString;


public AllChoiceQuestion(String questionText) {
    // initilize the question text value
            super(questionText);
    choiceString="";

}

   public void addChoice(String choice, boolean correct){
       super.addChoice(choice, correct);
       if(correct == true){
           count++;
           choiceString +=   "" + count+" " ;
            }
       super.setAnswer(choiceString.trim());
       }

   public void display(){
      System.out.println(note);
      super.display();
   }

   public String toString(){
       return note +"\n"+ super.toString();

   }
 }
```

This is the code for my instances

```
      ChoiceQuestion allchoicequestion1 = new AllChoiceQuestion("Which of the basic data type(s) has the size of 16 bit?");
      allchoicequestion1.addChoice("Char", true);
      allchoicequestion1.addChoice("Short", true);
      allchoicequestion1.addChoice("Float", false);
      allchoicequestion1.addChoice("Double", false);


      ChoiceQuestion allchoicequestion2 = new AllChoiceQuestion("Which of the basic data type(s) has the size of 64 bit?");
      allchoicequestion2.addChoice("Long", false);
      allchoicequestion2.addChoice("Doulbe", false);
      allchoicequestion2.addChoice("Byte", true);
      allchoicequestion2.addChoice("Int", true);
```

**So ChoiceStrng for allChoiceQuestion1 should be 1 2
and ChoiceString forallChoiceQuestion2 should be 3 4
but every time I tyee 3 4 as an answer for forallChoiceQuestion2 it gives me a false answer , but if I type 1 2 it would be correct**

Comment: `AllChoiceQuestion` class looks fine. Can you provide the code for creating instances where you are getting the problem?

Comment: I edit my post and I added the code at the bottom.

Comment: Oh I got it .. Thank you so much it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

choiceString is being initialized to "" every time in the constructor.

try

```
choiceString = questionText;
```

Comment: I need the value of ChoiceString to be empty because the user will input a value that will later be stored in choiceString; while questionText will hold a string that I , the programmer, will initialize when I create an instance of the class. So, they an not be assign to each other.

Comment: ...and if I could downvote my own answer I would. I guess I didnt read closely

Answer (score 0):

You would need to extends `AllChoiceQuestion` and have it's child class like `NumberChoiceQuestion` and `StringChoicQuestion` which will have their own implementation of `choiceString`, you need to overload `choiceString` implementation in child classes and create objects of child classes, this way you would have your child class specific `choiceString`

---

```
 public class NumberChoiceQuestion extends AllChoiceQuestion{
        this.choiceString; // Over written value of choiceString specific to NumberChoiceQuestion
    }

public class StringChoiceQuestion extends AllChoiceQuestion{
        this.choiceString; // Over written value of choiceString specific to StringChoiceQuestion
    }
```

Comment: ChoiceString is member of the AllChoiceQuestion class only, I am creating an instance of the AllChoiceQuestion itself. So There are not child class that extends AllChoiceQuestion. The problem is every time I create an instance of AllChoice the value of ChoiceString is shared by all instance, when it the case should be that each instance has its own copy of ChoiceStng.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not incrementing count when variable `correct` is false. Hence the choice string will always be 1 2.